# Get an array out of a two dimensional array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, multidimensional-array

In PostgreSQL, I have a two dimensional array like:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
```

and out of this array, I want to retrieve the whole 1st `([1,2,3])` array.
Sadly something like:

```sql
SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])[1];
```

doesn't work, since it returns a null.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i worked it out:

```
SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])[1][1:3]
```

does exacly what I wanted.

Comment: probably `select(array[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])[1][:]` would be a bit more generic

Comment: @Roman: Your comment is the definitive answer for Postgres 9.6 or later.

Comment: That works even better, since it saves me the time used for calculating the size of my array, unless Postgres does that either way. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create table test(id int, val int[][]);
> insert into test values (1, ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select id, val[1:1] from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val      
> -: | :--------
>  1 | {{1,2,3}}
> ```

> ```
> SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])[1:1]
> ```
>
> ```
> | array     |
> | :-------- |
> | {{1,2,3}} |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0af46e1895e4bd2bc7f9556b636a7257)*

Comment: Works well too. I will probably use Roman's way, since i already understand how it works. Thank you