# How to store specific data from a multi-dimensional array into a variable

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array, plpgsql

I have a multidimensional array like this one:

`coeficiente VARCHAR[2][2];`

What i have stored in this array is this information:

> ```
> {{"uwu","2"},{"owo","5"}}
> ```

I have another 2 variables called:

```
variable1 VARCHAR;
variable2 VARCHAR;
```

I want to save the "2" into the variable1, and the "5" into variable2 from this multidimensional array content example.

How can i do that?

I was thinking in maybe a for loop, but i still dunno how iterate inside of an ARRAY[][] structure in plpgsql.

The closest examples I could reach in internet were:

[stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48965127/postgresql-getting-an-array-out-of-a-two-dimensional-array). But they store an array out of a multidimensional array. I only need to get the variable inside of it.

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html). But it doesn't explain how to get inside of one specific "slot".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but:

```
variable1 := coeficiente[1][2];
variable2 := coeficiente[2][2];
```

will do what you want.

```
do
$$
declare
  coeficiente VARCHAR[2][2] := '{{"uwu","2"},{"owo","5"}}';
  variable1 VARCHAR;
  variable2 VARCHAR;  
begin
  variable1 := coeficiente[1][2];
  variable2 := coeficiente[2][2];
  
  raise notice 'var1=%', variable1;
  raise notice 'var2=%', variable2;
end;
$$
```

Will output:

```
var1=2
var2=5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over a two-dimensional array by using two for loops, also known as **nested loop**.
Similarly to loop an n-dimensional array you need n loops nested into each other.

Comment: Yes but how can I move inside of it **and** assign that information into my variable?
variable1:=coeficiente[1][2] for exampe?